# Can I use a SharePoint workflow to email the contents of a document?

Tags: php, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

The HR department in the company I work for has a SharePoint 2007 site filled with company policies. When changes are made to those documents they need a way for the contents of a document to be emailed to all the employees so they can review the new policy and click a button or link that says "OK I've read the new policy". So to speak. Similar to an EULA prompt. I know this is pretty straight forward using PHP on a "normal" website, but integration with SharePoint is really the goal.

I have seen ways using SharePoint Designer to make sophisticated workflows, [including some that send emails](http://rshelton.com/archive/2007/10/05/sharepoint-document-workflow-quothow-toquot---sending-an-email-with.aspx). However, none that I have seen will include the contents of the document.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure PHP should be the solution here? The only way in for PHP is using its COM or DOTNET classes, which are broken. Sure you could overcome this by making your own sharepoint .Net COM wrapper class in Visual Basic, but that would be extremely counter-productive.  It seems ASP is better suited.

Answer (score 1):

In the email you send, instead of sending the policy as an attachment, you could send a link which points to a PHP page (you state in your question it would be trivial for you to implement this in PHP), where you display (or attach) the document. At the end of the page you have a checkbox for the user to confirm he agrees with the policy. On submit, you save the new entry in your DB.

If you'd prefer not to write the PHP stuff, you'd better to migrate this question to Super User.